# Alert window physical home key not recoganized

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

First of all this is not a question related to "Reading the home key", I am aware that i cannot read home key presses. So before down voting it kindly read the question completely.

I am using an alert window for a popup. I am listening for the ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS broadcast to know when the home button is pressed to close the particular dialog. This works very well with software home button. For a physical home button (Similar to Home Button from Samsung Galaxy S series), this seems to be not working. 
       Actually it works great on Android 6.0 and above. But below Marshmallow the intent cannot be caught for physical home button press. Below is the code for my WindowManager.LayoutParms.

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP| Gravity.START;
    params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
```

Just a normal window. I am listening for intent from a service. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please help me guys. I have posted the same question in Google developers page in google plus. No answers from there. If there is no answers from here as well , where can i ask my question? Pls reply me.